# Android - finishing activity from another activity

Tags: android

is there any way, how to finish certain activity from a stack? I have service, which looks for updates, and when update is found, it opens update activity, where prompt for installation will appears. But after the installation appears I want to finish update activity, because it is not necessary to still be on a stack.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the update activity is launching another installation activity, then you may want to override `void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)` in the update activity, providing the following implementation.  Also, when the update activity launches the installation activity, it should do so with `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`, not with `startActivity(Intent)`.

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    finish();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

very helpful code

```
classname.static object.finish();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this please.

In first activity, define this before onCreate.

```
static TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity activityMain;
```

Then, in onCreate of first activity, write this.

```
activityMain = this;
```

Then, in second activity, write this when you want finish first one.

```
TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.activityMain.finish();
```

This will destroy first activity and when you press back on second activity, you will go back to home directly.

Comment: static reference to activity - Memory leak

Answer (score 2):

Use **finish()** method of the activity class to finish certain activity

```
this.finish(); // you can also use the application context  instead of this
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: If I have activity called update - can I call from other class update.finish() ? - that is what I need

Comment: I am using finish() regularly, but still I am not able to finish one activity on a stack from other (newer) activity

Comment: Use **finishActivity(int requestCode)** method inorder to finish another activity that you had previously started with **startActivityForResult(Intent, int)**.

Answer (score 0):

> But after the installation appears I want to finish update activity, because it is not necessary to still be on a stack.

When your "update activity" calls `startActivity()` to bring up "the installation", have it immediately call `finish()` on itself.

Comment: yea, problem is I am starting new activity from AsyncTask, so I cannot finish() on itself

Comment: @Hmyzak: Never start a new activity from an `AsyncTask`. That is user-hostile, causing an activity to randomly appear without warning.

Comment: via AsyncTask I am downloading file for update, when I finish download, I use onPostExecute to installing this app. I see no other way, you do?

Comment: @Hmyzak: Use an `IntentService` pre-Android 2.3 and `DownloadManager` on 2.3+, so the user is not tied to your app while the download is going on. Raise a `Notification` when the download is complete. When the user taps on the `Notification`, then install the app.