# i want call MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN in one activity and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP in another activity

Tags: java, android

```
 ImageView ii = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.picture);
ii.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
ImageView i2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btn_imagetest);
if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

//call activity one
}
if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
{
//call activity 2
}


return true;
}

});
```

when i touch on image 'ii' i should go to imgview(i2)(can be activity too) and when i leave the imgview should go away(back to same activitiy) ..(Note:imgview is covers full screen in phone)
i have no idea..how to proceed.

Comment: Did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're asking for information on how to start another Activity from the current Activity.  For information on that, take a look at [Android - finishing activity from another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523064/android-finishing-activity-from-another-activity)

Also, take a look at [the Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html), for a complete example.

Comment: No u wrongly understood...on motiondown i want to bring an imgview and motionup i want to be back in same screen